# Execute a Back Bean Method and get a Print in JSF + Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to develop a Billing application using JSF and PrimeFaces. The basic functionality requires to add several items to a bill and click the update button when the bill is complete. The printed bill must include details like BillId which is generate at the end of the backing bean settleBill method. It is needed to do it in one page so that after the print, the application is ready for a new bill.

I developed that as follows, but Printing and executing the method do not happen as expected.

```
 <p:commandButton value="Settle" action="#{billController.saveSelected()}" ajax="false" >
     <p:printer target="pDetails"  /> 
 </p:commandButton>
```

When I use without Ajax, Printing part is ok, but action is not executed. When used with Ajax,  command is executed, but print is not working. I used an action listner instead of the action, still the same result.

```
<p:commandButton value="Settle" actionListener="#{billController.settleBill}" ajax="false" >
    <p:printer target="pDetails"  /> 
</p:commandButton>
```

How can I execute a backing bean method at the same time getting printouts with final values like Bill Id, which is generated after the backing bean method is fully executed. I want to achieve it in a single page so that after every bill the screen is ready for the next bill.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use without Ajax, To make printing as well as action to work you have to use following code:

```
<p:commandButton value="Settle" actionListener="#{billController.settleBill}">
<f:ajax execute="@this"/>
    <p:printer target="pDetails"  /> 
  </p:commandButton>
```

and In the settleBill method declare it with ActionEvent like below:

```
public void settleBill (ActionEvent actionevent) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc"  actionListener="#{movimentoBean.test}" />

           <p:commandButton value="Imprimir" type="button" 
              icon="ui-icon-print" onclick="rc();PF('visDialog').hide()"
              style="display:block;margin-bottom: 20px">
              <p:printer target=":formMovimentos:etiqueta" />
           </p:commandButton>
```

public void test(ActionEvent actionevent) {}

Comment: Can you explain this answer a little bit? It can be hard to understand code-only answers.